# Rotate Camera Down Without Side Rotation

Tags: camera

I have a simple scene set up with a camera that moves around. I want to point the camera down to get a better view of some objects. This would be trivial if the camera was on one of the x or y lines, but it isn't. It is between the two, so when I try to rotate it, I get unwanted rotation to the side too. Gif for more info: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAnfX.jpg

Thanks!

Comment: When you choose Rotate (r), they try entering 'x' to limit the rotation to the X axis, which I think is the axis you want (although it may be 'y' or 'z' that you want)

Comment: @james_t That is what I have been doing already. Since the camera is not pointing straight on one axis, it rotates the camera to the side as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press <kbd>N</kbd> on your keyboard and a menu will open. Click on the "View" tab and look for a checkbox next to "Camera to view." Click on this checkbox and press <kbd>N</kbd> again to close the menu. Now, switch to the view of the camera that you're having the problem with and hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and the <kbd>MMB</kbd> while dragging your mouse down. To clarify [here is a Link to a .gif](https://mega.nz/file/F0dVVQzD#bUZt_4upzDCTdwqdoZVpzL-oCjqua9iiNw77CoYYBHQ).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This does solve my question, but I was wondering if there was a way to have more precision (like how you can input numbers when rotating)

Comment: You can type decimals (e.i. 1.28, 23.86). Just type the period on your keyboard just like you'd click numbers.

Comment: I've got it. Type 'R' for rotate, then press "X" two times. Try rotating then. What this does is it changes the x-axis from global to local.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! I never knew that was a thing.